# Nginx set a variable conditionally

Tags: nginx

I want to allow 1GB uploads on a specific subdomain of my site called `upload.xxx.xx.xx`.

Currently I am trying something like:

```
server {
    if ( $host = 'upload.xxx.xx.xx' ) {
           client_max_body_size 1000M;
    }
}
```

But of course it gives me an error about the `client_max_body_size` not supposed to be there.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want without duplicating the two `vhost`s, all the settings are the same otherwise, or on the flip side should I not bother to go to the trouble of making sure the user can only upload greater than 10MB on `upload` subdomain?

Comment: You will need two separate server blocks. I don't think there's any other way.

Comment: If you just don't want repetition of lines, you could use `include` to duplicate configuration without duplicating lines.

Comment: @Grumpy good point could use includes to solve this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it works specifically with `client_max_body_size`, but, in general, nginx does allow to do exactly what you describe.

```
server {
    set $cmbs 100K;
    if ( $host = 'upload.xxx.xx.xx' ) {
           set $cmbs 1000M;
    }
    client_max_body_size $cmbs;
}
```

Comment: Sweet works cheers

Comment: this does not work as it gives "client_max_body_size" directive invalid value in ...

Comment: @muayyadalsadi, i doubt this has gotten broken since having been tested by the OP; but feel free to post another question with complete details and what you use in the config, and reference it here, we'll take a look

Comment: I see the same thing as muayyadalsadi. Full details: http://serverfault.com/questions/722249/conditionally-set-client-max-body-size

Comment: Maybe you can solve this by defining an `upstream` and use `proxy_pass` to redirect at the right condition?