# Conditionally set client_max_body_size

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set `client_max_body_size` conditionally. I've followed the configuration suggested in the answer to [Nginx set a variable conditionally](https://serverfault.com/questions/562816/nginx-set-a-variable-conditionally), but it is not working for me.

The following configuration file is sufficient to reproduce:

```
daemon off;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /dev/stderr debug;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
  access_log /dev/stdout;
  server {
    listen 80;
    location /test {
      set $cmbs 1m;
      if ($arg_long) {
        set $cmbs 5m;
      }
      client_max_body_size $cmbs;
      echo $cmbs;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to start Nginx with this configuration, it halts and complains

> nginx: [emerg] "client_max_body_size" directive invalid value in /opt/nginx/nginx.conf:16

If I remove the offending directive, Nginx starts and I echo the set value back in the way I expect.

I am running openresty/1.7.10.1.
I've also tried the above small config on nginx/1.9.4.

Comment: What do you mean with $arg_long?

Comment: 5 years later I don't entirely recall. From context, I think it's a stand-in for "some kind of test that says whether or not I want to accept a long argument". For example, users who present the correct auth-token might be allowed large uploads while anonymous users get a small limit. Or requests from a set of white-listed IPs might get the larger limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nginx as of version 1.9.4 does not support variable client_max_body_size.](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/586)

Comment: I get the exact same error message. Did this work for you?

Comment: Nope, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this by defining an `upstream` and use `proxy_pass` to redirect at the right condition:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: I believe the problem here happens _before_ a call to proxy_pass. If the request is larger than Nginx's limit, then it's going to fail the request before it considers passing to an upstream.